# Why a function return a array and no a vector?

Tags: python-2.7

Why is the reason for this?
when use a program with a function return this.

```
[array([ 48.29946595]), array([-38.05412469]), array([ 585.44807213])]
```

but i want to return this:

```
[48.29946595,-38.05412469, 585.44807213]
```

How to could solver this.

Comment: Can you share the code?

Comment: https://mega.nz/#!n5pQ0axb!BJFccvcn1_7Z6mbY4bqurGicIDeoJiREDsGru4Yhv1Y

Answer (score 0):

I'm going to take a guess that these arrays are from numpy, or something similar, and say that you just need to get the 0th index for each value in that list (i.e. `value[0]`). A short, one-line way to do this is as follows:

```
cleanedReturnedArray = map(lambda x: x[0], myReturnedArray)
```

Or, perhaps in a more pythonic way:

```
cleanedReturnedArray = [ x[0] for x in myReturnedArray ]
```

Comment: this is the code:   
https://mega.nz/#!n5pQ0axb!BJFccvcn1_7Z6mbY4bqurGicIDeoJiREDsGru4Yhv1Y

Comment: strange is when put vectors points in the function return vector, when use this function inside other function return with array. I cant understand that.